# Non-zero Nat is Greater than Zero

Tags: lean

In a specific situation, I needed the following proof:

```lean
def Nat.zero_lt (n:Nat)(p:n ≠ 0) : 0 < n :=
by
  match n with
  | Nat.zero => contradiction
  | Nat.succ m => simp
```

That's fine, but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this?  For example, by using an existing `Nat` lemma (but I couldn't find a direct match).  When faced with a question like this, searching through the Matlib4 documentation does not seem to yield results very easily.

Comment: https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Std/Data/Nat/Init/Lemmas.html#Nat.pos_of_ne_zero

Comment: The exact? tactic from mathlib should find Nat.pos_of_ne_zero for you

Comment: From a [Lean cheatsheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/madvorak/lean4-cheatsheet/main/lean-tactics.pdf), I eventually found it: `import Mathlib.Tactic.LibrarySearch`

Comment: Just `import Mathlib` and don't worry about missing imports ever again